# Can't display tkinter gui from within docker

Tags: python, user-interface, docker, tkinter, x11

No matter what I try, I'm getting the error:
`_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "*whatever I set as DISPLAY*"`
while trying to run GUI within docker. I tried adding `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY` flags to the docker run command, but it didn't help at all.

The setup I'm trying to run currently is: Computer1 with Ubuntu 17.10 is running a docker container (Ubuntu as well), I want to run the GUI on Computer1 display - :1.

However, the end goal would be to have Computer1 run without any display connected and have the docker use the display of Computer2 (Ubuntu as well) that connects to Computer1 via ssh.

Comment: Have you tried what is recommended here? http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

Comment: I did try the launch commands, but I gotta admit I didn't try running the sample dockerfile they provided